# Limit and group by rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with items inside :

```
id    title     body    category_id    likes
1     title1    body1    17            57
2     title2    body2    14            35
3     title3    body3    11            16
4     title4    body4    11            96
5     title5    body5    14            78
6     title6    body6    11            64
```

And I want to group by this table by category_id and order by likes :

```
id    title     body    category_id    likes
1     title1    body1    17            57
5     title5    body5    14            78
2     title2    body2    14            35
4     title4    body4    11            96
6     title6    body6    11            64
3     title3    body3    11            16
```

I think I must do a subquery but how ?

Edit : I use MySQL DB

Edit 2 : I forgot to mention that I wanted to limit the results to 3 rows per category_id because I want to display the 3 most liked item per category

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in the sample result you provided there's no real `GROUP BY` applied. It's just sorted by `category_id` and `likes`. To get expected result simply:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
ORDER BY category_id DESC, likes DESC
```

Comment: yes thanks ! but I forgot to mention that I want only 3 results for each category_id ... it's why I wanted to mix group by (which is not a group by) and limit

Comment: So... you only want the top 3 results with more likes for each category? Modify the original question with those new requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting the question as:  I want to order by the total likes for each category.

You can use a subquery in the `order by` clause, so one method is:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (select sum(t2.likes) from t t2 where t2.category_id = t.category_id),
         category_id;
```

You can also do this using window functions:

```
select t.*
from t
order by sum(t.likes) over (partition by t.category_id),
         category_id;
```

Comment: that query with a window function will offcource only work in MySQL 8.0+  which isn't production ready jet.

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . The question wasn't tagged with MySQL when I answered it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry - it seems not to be possible in MySQL - Postgres would work.
There are to limitations: 
1. no limit usage allowed in subquery when using keyword IN
2. no refering to parent parent columns in subsubquery

there for the following answer does not work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table t1
WHERE t1.id IN (SELECT id 
                FROM your_table t2 
                WHERE t1.category_id=t2.category_id 
                ORDER BY likes DESC 
                LIMIT 3)
ORDER BY category_id DESC, likes DESC
```

Comment: exactly, MySQL doesnt allow LIMIT into a IN condition ... but maybe with a JOIN ?

Comment: join does not help. it is necessary to preselect the ids by using limit 3. and using limit on the join does not give you the wanted result. mysql sucks